# Вывод информации из базы с foreign key Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, база-данных, laravel

У меня есть страница отправляющиая парметр в данный код после чего он выполняет выборку из базы numbers но при этом выводит все посты в том числе и те которые не опубликованны , и тут встал вопрос как именно задат ему второй параметр который не будет дават выписыват из базы не опубликованную инфу

Вот мой код на данный момент но к сожалению он приводит просто к ошибке =)

```
public function search(){
   /* $numb = Numbers::where("nmb_title",Request::input('nmb_title').'-'.Request::input('nmb_title1').'-'.Request::input('nmb_title2'))->get();*/
    $nmb = Request::input('nmb_title').'-'.Request::input('nmb_title1').'-'.Request::input('nmb_title2');
    $posta = Posts::where("published",1)-> $numb = Numbers::where('nmb_title',$nmb)->get();
    /*$numb = Numbers::where('nmb_title',$nmb) -> Posts::where("published",1) ->get();*/
  dd($numb);

    return view('search', compact('numb','posta'));
```

Comment: wtf  $posta = Posts::where("published",1)`->` $numb = Numbers::where('nmb_title',$nmb)->get();`

Comment: ,это была просто послдняя идея =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

кароче пару днепй опытов привело меня к тому что надо использовать join для проверки параметров в мое случае получилос вот это

```
$nmb = Request::input('nmb_title').'-'.Request::input('nmb_title1').'-'.Request::input('nmb_title2');

$numb =Posts::join('numbers','posts.id','=','numbers.posts_id')->where('numbers.nmb_title','=',$nmb)->where('posts.published',1)->get();
```